# Two constructors (with & without parameter), no input -> run without parameter. Skipping constructors in the classes above

Tags: c++, class, constructor, subclass

Right now I got a class with multiple subclasses. All classes consist of a constructor asking for data input in each class (it's private, so each class ask for it's own data). Right now, I'm working on a subclass that will ask for a name. If the user presses ENTER (no input), it'll run the constructor of the class without parameter. If there's any input, it'll put that input into the class' constructor that has parameters.

My problem is that whenever I put no input, it asks all the question it is supposed to (from the classes above the subclass), and works well. However, it skips the first letter of the name. E.g I write "Jordan" as name, and it gets saved as "ordan".

Second, if I put no input, it'll use the constructor without parameters. It asks for the name (it's being asked by the "main" consutrctor, the main class. I write in the name, and it skips all the other questions from the subconstructors - which it is not supposed to do.

I have tried to just make an object inside case 'F': like Fish f1; and that works, but that is not what I am supposed to do here (homework). What can it be? I thought it could be the cin.ignore(); fucking up, but I need it there.

**I find it hard to explain, but if you do the following with the code below (write in console).**

1. You'll be asked to write "F" to add a fish, write F.
2. Write a random name (not empty).
3. All other questions will be answered, which it is not supposed to be. The constructor should ask the questions - here's the first
   problem.

**And again, start on new:**

1. Write "F" to add a fish.
2. Write nothing, just press enter when asked for name.
3. Write a random name.
4. Write y or n on the freshwater question, same goes to next question.
5. You'll see the Name has lost it first letter.

Here's the code (shortened):

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int STRLEN = 20;

// FUNCTIONS
bool Question(); // User input y or n, sets the correct bool value
void Answer(bool n);    // Changes true to yes, false to no

class Animal {
private:
    char name[STRLEN];

public:
    Animal() { cout << "\nAnimal name: "; cin.ignore();  cin.getline(name, STRLEN); }
    Animal(char nam[]) { strcpy(name, nam); } // Const with parameter, sent from Fish-class

    void writeName() { cout << "Name: " << name << '\n'; } 
};

class AnimalWater : public Animal {
private:
    bool freshwater;

public:
    AnimalWater() { cout << "Freshwater? (y/n): "; freshwater = Question(); }
    AnimalWater(char name[]) : Animal(name) { } // Sendes name (used by Fish) up to Animal-class
    void writeWater() { cout << "Freshwater? "; Answer(freshwater); cout << '\n'; }
};

class Fisk : public AnimalWater {
private:
    bool haveGills;

public:
    Fisk() { cout << "Does the fish have gills? (y/n): "; haveGills = Question(); }
    Fisk(char name[]) : AnimalWater(name) { } // Send the Fish name up to Animal-class
    void writeGills() { Answer(haveGills); }
};

int main() {
    char choice;

    cout << "\nWrite F to add a fish: ";
    cin >> choice; choice = toupper(choice); 

    while (choice != 'Q') {             // If not Q(uit), run
        switch (choice) {
        case 'F': {
            char fishname[STRLEN];
            cout << "Name of the fish: "; cin.ignore();
            cin.getline(fishname, STRLEN);

            if (strlen(fishname) > 0) {  // if user input > 0
                Fisk f1(fishname); // sned fishname as parameter to the Fish constructor
                f1.writeName(); f1.writeWater(); f1.writeGills();
            }
            else {  // else use the constructor without parameter
                Fisk f1; f1.writeName(); f1.writeWater(); f1.writeGills(); 
            }
            break;
        }
        }

        cout << "\n\nWhat to do? ";
        cin >> choice; choice = toupper(choice);
    }
    return 0;
}

bool Question() { 
    char answer; cin >> answer; answer = toupper(answer); 
    if (answer == 'Y') return true; 
    else return false;
}

void Answer(bool n) {
    if (n) cout << "yes";
    else cout << "no";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with eating first letter happens because you are eating one character in constructor of `Animal`. Calling `cin.ignore()` ignores one character. This is ok if you are using `cin.getline()` after `cin >>`, because `operator>>` leaves `\n` in buffer and `cin.getline()` would read empty string. However, in your case it does not take place. You should use `cin >>` method everywhere.

Also, getting input from user in constructor of model isn't a good approach in most cases.